# Given two memory addresses can I move the data from one address to another without that data coming into the registers

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

I have recently started looking in to the x86 architecture,

my basic goal is to move data that is in the main memory to a specialised memory e.g. Scratchpad Memory, without that data coming into the cpu registers.
For example if I give the cpu 2 addresses, can it copy that data to the specialised memory just through the data buses?

I had a look at this (MOVS)https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html but am not sure if it brings the data into the cpu registers or not

Comment: `MOVS` brings the data to the cpu but not into visible registers. You might be interested in some DMA instead, if available.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  What benefit would it offer over using a CPU register?

Comment: `rep movs` is efficient on modern CPUs, but a well-optimized loop using AVX `vmovups` loads/stores can usually beat it and has lower startup overhead.  If you don't mind using some architectural YMM registers.  Either way the CPU core is doing loads and stores, and the memory controllers are attached to the CPU itself.  When you say scratchpad, do you mean Xeon Phi with its EDRAM configured as scratchpad instead of cache?  AFAIK you just have to copy normally; there isn't a way to bypass the CPU core, whether or not you use any architectural registers.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I need this, as the data I would bring into the scratchpad memory would not be used immediately but later on(but it is a lot of data and I dont want the CPU to stall while just copying it), also i will be using later on frequently again and again and I don't want the cache to hold this data continuously (related to graph applications).

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes basically an EDRAM configured as scratchpad to meet my requirements for graph processing. So basically there is no way I can copy the data without it passing it through the CPU?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Xeon Phi's system architecture, but unless there's some DMA engine to copy large chunks of data between memory and EDRAM or vice versa (with large setup overhead), bringing it in a CPU core is the only way to go.  Using an architectural register as a temporary or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @PeterCordes, okay, will look at DMA, and just a question out of context, if you can help, when  data is moving from the main memory to the cache does that data also  pass through the cpu registers or not?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to.  The CPU core basically sees main memory *through* cache, so loads into registers pull data into the cache if it wasn't there already.  (We're talking about the small L1 / L2 / L3 caches here, or also EDRAM when configured as a cache, not scratchpad where it has an actual address.)